# Parallels 7 after El Capitan update

Tags: macos, parallels-desktop

I have Parallels 7 on my Macbook Pro. I just installed El Capitan onto my Macbook and now I can't open Parallels. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4):

You're going to have to upgrade to Parallels 10 or Parallels 11. See this Parallels knowledgeable article: [Parallels Desktop and Mac OS (Host) compatibility](http://kb.parallels.com/en/114381)

There is a free [trial demo of Parallels 11](http://trial.parallels.com). So you may be able to convert your old Parallels 7 file in advance of paying for it.

Next time you update OS X be sure to check its compatibility with the version of Parallels you're running. Parallels is a program that often breaks with an OS X update.